How to assign a pipewire sink for an application that creates and removes ports intermittently?
I'm trying to find a simple solution to connect a wine application to a specific skin (not the default one). The problem is that application doesn't emit sound constantly, but intermittently, very briefly (some milliseconds). I can see it in pavucontrol during sounds, but not enough to be able to click on it to change the associated sink.
So I'm trying to achieve this connection via command line:

I can see this app in "Clients" section of wpctl status
it has the id 115. wpctl inspect 115 doesn't help so much

As far as I understand, this client seems to create a port when playing sound, than destroy this port as soon as the sound is played.
I've seen that I could make a Lua script to make automated connections, but I was hoping to be able to have a simpler solution, as sometimes I need to play those sounds over bluetooth, sometimes on my internal speakers, sometimes on my usb-hearphone ...
Is there any way to tell to Pipewire: "each time this client will create a port, connect this port to this sink" ?
Maybe is this a Wine problem ? Not sure if it's a best practice to create and remove ports like that 
